# Django queryset efficiency

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have an `Item` object which has a ForeignKey to a `Receipt` object.

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(Receipt)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cost = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)

    ...
```

I display the receipts using a generic view.

```
class ReceiptView(DetailView):
    model = Receipt
```

And then on the template, I want to show all items on the receipt.

```
<ul>
{% for item in object.item_set.all %}
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This works fine for smaller data sets. One of the receipt objects has 1600 items related to it. Loading the page for that receipt is incredibly slow. Using Django Debug Toolbar I notice that Django is executing 1 query per item.

If I alter the list item in the template so that rather than displaying a property of the item, I just display the item itself, Django just executes a single query.

```
<ul>
{% for item in object.item_set.all %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Unfortunately I need to display about 10 of the item's properties in the template. Is there someway I can tell Django to execute a single query to get all items and all of their properties?

Comment: You probably want to look into using `select_related`

Comment: A long list of 1600 related items is definitely not a good idea. Consider using pagination for the related items.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prefetch_related`. Since you are doing a reverse foreign key lookup, you're essentially working with a ManyToMany relationship. `prefetch_related` will do a separate query under the hood, to retrieve and then cache all of the `Receipt` objects for you.

Since you're using generic views, rather than specifying a `model`, you can specify a `queryset`.

```
class ReceiptView(DetailView):
    queryset = Receipt.objects.prefetch_related('related_items')
```

In order to do this, you'll have to specify a `related_name` in your `Item` model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(Receipt, related_name='related_items')
```

Comment: Do you mean `queryset = Receipt.objects.prefetch_related('related_items')` in the view?

Comment: Also, I'm open to overwriting `get_context_data()` on the view and making the `Item`s related to the `Receipt` available to the template that way if that seems like a better option (avoiding the ManyToMany of the reverse foreign key lookup). A simple `context['items'] = Item.objects.filter(receipt=self.object)` still results in excessive queries in the template, but maybe there is a way to make that direction more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I meant Receipt. I corrected it. There's no need to change your models around. Did the solution not work for you?